# Creating a client and server side socket connection and keeping it connected in php

Tags: php, sockets

If we create a socket in server side then it runs in a infinite loop, cant we do something like this for the client side? Can we create a listening mood in a infinite loop? Do I need to create a new socket every for this every time?

Here is my code, it writes only once, when I try to write after `socket_read` it doesn't work.

Server side code

```
<?php
$host = "192.168.56.1";
$port = 8080;
$message = "Hello Client";
set_time_limit(0);
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");
$result = socket_bind($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not bind to socket\n");
$result = socket_listen($socket) or die("Could not set up socket listener\n");
echo 'listining ip '.$host." at port ".$port;
while(true){
$com = socket_accept($socket) or die("Could not accept incoming connection\n");
$input = socket_read($com, 1024) or die("Could not read input\n");
$input = trim($input);
echo '
Client says: '.$input;
socket_write($com, $message , strlen ($message)) or die("Could not write output\n");
}
echo '
server closed';
socket_close($com);
socket_close($socket);
?>
```

client side code

```
<?php
$host    = "192.168.56.1";
$port    = 8080;
$message = "Hello Server side";
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");
$result = socket_connect($socket, $host, $port) or die ("Could not connect to server\n");

socket_write($socket, $message, strlen($message)) or die("Could not send data to server\n");
$result = socket_read($socket, 1024) or die("Could not read server response\n");
socket_write($socket,$message, strlen($message)) or die("Could not send data to server\n");

echo "Server  says :";//.$result;
socket_close($socket);
?>
```

Comment: You can do anything you want in programming. You can create a client that's always connected. The question is - does it make sense and why would you want or need to do it?

Comment: I am making a android chat app ,I want keep listning server  and client incoming cammand

Comment: And? Where's the problem?

Comment: problem is socket write works only once... when I try to write after socket_read() id does not work

Comment: If your client would be in an infinite loop, how would it know which messages to send? What would be the modus operandi of your client? There are some details missing. Is there any chance you can take a look at IRC protocol? It seems to me that's what you're after, and there's plenty of examples, in PHP and in JavaScript on how to implement it and create a chat app.

Answer (score 0):

> If we create a socket in server side then it runs in a infinite loop,
>   cant we do something like this for the client side? Can we create a
>   listening mood in a infinite loop?

Of course - if your server and client would send and receive strictly in turn, you could simply change the `socket_read` line in the **client** to

```
while ($result = socket_read($socket, 1024))
```

> Do I need to create a new socket every for this every time?

No, you must not, since it wouldn't be the same connection.

But for a more complete **server** example which handles multiple connections and disconnections, cf. this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38782141/2413201) to *How to write server for chat program in php by using socket*.